# Sorting of uI grid column containing Angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have recently started using Angular ui-grid. I am not very well versed with the internals of the library.

I had a `ui-grid` column that required to display percentages. SO I added the following filter to my `app` and used it along with `ui-grid` `cellFilter` property.

```
module.filter('percentage', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (!input) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return input + '%';
        }
    };
})
```

This worked fine, but while sorting this column. The sorting works unexpectedly. Suppose if I have 3 rows with values `100,200,300`. I expect it can have only two sorted states `100,200,300` and `300,200,100`. But if I keep clicking the header of this column I get a third state as `200, 300, 100` or as `100, 300,200`. I am even not sure what the pattern is for this state.

If I am right, The angular filter works only on the `views` and do not impact model of the field. So I do not think adding `filter` can have an impact on sorting.

Apart from that the two expected sorting (ASCENDING, DESCENDING) appears perfectly, the only problem being the appearance of third. How do I resolve this issue.

Am I missing any implementation ?? Kindly help me resolve this.

Edit: This issue occurs for string column as well. In my understanding there can only be one ASCENDING and one DESCENDING state as far as sorting is considered. But I get more arrangements.

Comment: when using sorting from ui-grid you have a third state - default order- which is data displayed in the order in which it has been loaded. This can be seen for their example also http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting

Comment: Thanks@rave Is there a way that if once sorted the rows thereafter should toggle only between ASCENDING and DESCENDING orders avoiding the default order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sortDirectionCycle` to remove the third state of sorting.

```
columnDefs: [
   { field: 'name', sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC] },
   { field: 'gender', sortDirectionCycle: [uiGridConstants.ASC, uiGridConstants.DESC] },
   { field: 'company', enableSorting: false }
]
```

From document, When clicking on a column heading the sort direction will cycle to ascending, then descending, then back to unsorted. You may rearrange this cycle or skip part of it by setting the sortDirectionCycle columnDef option. For more details check this link [sortDirectionCycle](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#sortdirectioncycle)